# Enclosing bounds of text in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I need the width and height of the enclosing bounds of a string with limit on width or on height. Found two method, but they does not exactly what I am looking for.

[Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)) `.measureText()` `.getTextBounds()`

How can I set a limit, i.e. I do not want the bound's width be bigger than 300px?

In iOS `NSString`'s `boundingRect` method calculate this, or the `sizeToFit`.

Comment: When using Paint, you paint the text yourself. So you can paint it letter by letter or word by word and if the measuredText of your text + the next letter is exceeding 300px you just don't paint it or switch the line.

Comment: I need to put in "\n" characters?

Comment: no, you dont `need to put in "\n" characters`: read about `android.text.Layout` class

Comment: @pskink I see, it is like constraints in iOS, is it possible to set the **height** parameter is the **variing bonds component** in layout XML?

Comment: no, it lays out the input text, with the fixed width: just like one column in the newspaper - all you need is to pass your text and maximum width and the height of this layout will be calculated based on text and max width

Answer (score 0):

I think you not fully understand what `Paint.measureText` doing.
This method just calculates **width of text**, using Paint inner params.
If you want to limit your text, for example ellipsize text you can use [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012232/draw-text-ellipsized-to-a-canvas)

Otherwise, `Paint.getTextBounds` needs in Rect object, that this method will fill. But no limitation here.

Comment: `ellipsize` will truncate text. I need to calculate the needed height for a fixed width, if text, font and fontsize is known. Do you know how to do it in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276853/how-to-measure-textview-height-based-on-device-width-and-font-size) the answer. Need [View.MeasureSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html) to calculate height f width is limited.

Comment: @pskink nothing, but `View.MeasureSpec` can calculate required height if width is limited

Comment: so probably your problem is a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: @pskink I think my PROBLEM was quite specific. Refered two paint method to show I put effort to find solution.