# Android text is cut off on a fixed height TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider this layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Cupertino, California, that designs, develops, and sells consumer electronics, computer software, and online services."
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="top"/>
```

What I want the TextView to do is to figure out how many lines it can fit in 160dp and places three dots if room is not enough. However the text is cut off instead:
[image]

How can I achieve the above behavior? I assume I can do it by just specifying some attribute on the layout resource file. Thanks.

Comment: i think this will solve your issue: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: Found this on SO looks like it might do what you need [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012232/draw-text-ellipsized-to-a-canvas)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYrpEAz_A1U
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to achieve this by simply specifying attributes on the layout resource file.

If you look at the `setEllipsize()` method in `TextView`, you'll see that it says:

> Causes words in the text that are longer than the view's width to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. You may also want to setSingleLine() or setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean) to constrain the text to a single line. Use null to turn off ellipsizing. If setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, only TextUtils.TruncateAt.END and TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE are supported (other ellipsizing types will not do anything).

From that documentation, you can see that ellipsis in `TextView` is actually highly dependent on two factors: **view width** and **number of lines**.

As such, I recall that an ellipsis might not show up for a `TextView` if it doesn't know the maximum number of lines that your `TextView` can have.

So for your intended behavior, this isn't possible because you're depending on the View's height instead. You want to use a specific height then have a TextView calculate the amount of lines that can be shown within that height. Finally, if the amount of lines needed is greater than the amount shown, you want to show ellipses.

That's... not possible with how the ellipses in `TextView` is coded. It simply wasn't meant for that.

Therefore, if you want this behavior, you need to either:

1. Create a custom `TextView` for your specific ellipses implementation
2. Manually calculate the amount of lines visible, then use `setMaxLines()` on that `TextView`

For the second option, you can calculate this by using the `TextView` methods `getHeight()` and `getLineHeight()`.

For example:

```
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);

textview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        final int maxLines = textview.getHeight() / textview.getLineHeight();
        textview.setMaxLines(maxLines);
    }
});
```

In my example, I'm doing this inside a `ViewTreeObserver` to avoid `getHeight()` calling a size of 0.

The second option should be able to get the behavior you want, but if you want this for every `TextView`, you should consider creating a custom `TextView` instead.

Comment: I was looking for this answer for a day... awesome, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout_gravity on the TextView to fill